# Auto save my edits

Tags: plone, add-on, autosave

I have only been able to find 1 add-on for autosaving/draft-save. 
The problem is that if the browser crashes while you are editing content of a page, or created a new page, that changes will be lost. And it's not always, that one will remember to save manually.

The add-on I found and installed is:  plone.app.drafts
I installed it using buildout, and activated it in the add-on. Though it doesn't seem to be working for me. Has anyone managed to make it work? To test it I crashed the browser (and also just closed the browser while editing), and according to the documentation for this add-on, the saved content should be in portal_drafts. But there is nothing there.

I followed this [document](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.drafts/1.0a2).

Stackoverflow has the best auto save future EVER. It would be nice with such, but just a normal auto save will do fine.

Are there other plone fans out there that have managed to overcome this hurdle? Like found a nice add-on to help out?

Answer (score 2):

do you want to auto-save input in richtextfields (tinymce) or all fields?

for tinymce there is a plugin you could try to add:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopyx.tinymceplugins.tinyautosave/1.0.1

Comment: It is the body text of a page that I want to autosave. A bit like google docs, that saves the project automatically, so that all edits don't get lost by a crash. Thanks for this onfo, I will try the tinymceplugin too